# TikZ: Bend text so that it follows a line

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels

I have two arrows going from a node on the left to a node on the right. Both arrows are slightly bent. I want to label the arrows with text that is bent just like the arrows. This is as far as I've got:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {One}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {Two};
\draw [->, thick] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\draw [->, thick] (One) to  [bend left=45] (Two);
\node (mental) at (0,1.75) {Some bent text};
\node (non-mental) at (0,-1.75) {Some more bent text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You want the _node text_ to be bent? I'm not sure that's easy...

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear there. I don't really care what it is that gets bent. I just want bent text as the end result. My first try was to do this with nodes.

Comment: Note that for straight node labels you normally attach the node to the path and not place it manually: `\draw [->, thick] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two) node [midway] {some text};`

Comment: how to specify same decoration to all paths, like in tikz environment

Comment: @gangadhar You'll have better luck asking a new question than using an answer to ask a question.

Comment: @gangadhar [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  As AlanMunn says, please post a new question - link to this if needed.  Also, it would be _very_ helpful to to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it, and instead can focus on the specific question at hand.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This can be done by the `decorations.text` library gives you a `text along path` decoration. See the PGF/TikZ manual (v2.10) on page 337, section 30.6 *Text decorations* for more details. You can't draw and decorate the path at the same time directly, but can use `postaction={..}` to decorate the path after you have drawn it (Thanks goes to Alan Munn for this tip).

To format the text place the style macros between `|` in the `text` argument. Non-English characters need to be included in braces, e.g. `text={|\itshape|Some Text {ö} more text}`. One issue is to raise the font (it is just placed really on the path!). I looked into the source code and found out that the font macros are placed before each single processed character but with an `\relax` between it, i.e. `<your style>\relax<character>`. You could define a macro which takes two arguments, the first is the `\relax` and the second the character, then use `\raisebox{<length>}{<content>}` to raise or lower the character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift|Some more bent text}}}] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily\myshift|Some bent text}}}]      (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post this solution too, but I was unable to figure out how to move the text so that (i) it doesn't overlap the line so much and (ii) have the lower text wrap *under* the line (without being upside-down.)  Do you know how to do that? BTW, you can also add the decoration as a `postaction` to the `\draw` command instead of having both the `\path` and `\draw` commands.

Comment: @Alan: `postaction` is a good idea. I'm currently also look for a technique how to move the text.

Comment: This is great. However, I also want to do exactly the things that Alan Munn suggests.

Comment: You could shift the coordinates for the text path with `($(One)+(0,1)$)` for example (needs `calc` library). I don’t know why `yshift=1cm` doesn’t work. Maybe because you don’t use absolute coordinates.

Comment: @Tobi: `(One) to (Two)` gives quit different results than when both are shifted. In the first case the border of both are are used and in the second case the center is shifted and then used. Also note that you can use `yshift` inside the coordniate spec: `([yshift=1cm]One)`, which also doesn't work well enough.

Comment: That's great. There's only one problem left for me now. I'm trying to change the font by putting in "font=\sffamily" on different places (I've declared it as a parameter for the TikZ environment but it seems to be overridden by "decoration.text") but I can't get it to change.

Comment: @Martin: Ahh … I didn’t know that. But there must be a way to shift the whole path as it is (I hope …)

Comment: @Speldosa: `font` is only used for nodes AFAIK. Styles can be given between delimiters which are set using `text format delimiters={<start>}{<begin>}`, by default both are `|`, so use `text={|\somefontcommands|your text}`.

Comment: @Speldosa: I think you’ll have to aply the font directly to the path’s text, like `text={|\sffamily| Some Text}`; please see page 337 an 338 of the pgfmanual. EDIT: Martin was faster …

Comment: @Martin and Tobi: Thanks. That solved the problem. I had the feeling that I had to use some other command and looked in the manual for the answer but couldn't find it. Good thing you could help me out!

Comment: OT: It's times like these I'm wondering why I even bother using TikZ. Then again, when I see the final result, I remember why :)

Comment: @MartinScharrer It's possible to replace `\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}` by `raise=1ex`  \draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|Some more bent text}}}] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two); I think that is valable since pgf 2.1

Comment: Is there any way to put a fill on the "text along path" text? e.g. when using this over an image, it would make the text stand out better. I could not get the usual `fill=white` function to work.

Comment: In the aforementioned example, text parameter ```text={|\sffamily\myshift|Some more bent text}``` works fine with plaintext. How can I use text with super-script here? I tried using the following ```text={|\sffamily\myshift|$value^a}``` but it does not work.

Comment: @ex1led: try `text={|\sffamily\myshift|value{${}^a$}}`, but it might just work for single characters.

Answer (score 38):

You can use `raise` to place the text

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-2.5ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|Some more bent text}}}] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=1ex,text along path,text align=center,text={|\sffamily|Some bent text}}}]      (One) to [bend left=45] (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using raise is not generally a good idea, as it'll increase inter-character space in the text along the path. Depending on one's specific situation, it may be better to `\draw` one path, and then `\path` another that is pushed slightly outward and along which the text is placed.

Comment: @chsk I'm not sure that writing bend text so that it follows a line is a good idea !

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, but isn't that what it's about? To give an example of what I meant: if you have e.g. `\draw [postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=0.35cm,text along path,reverse path,text align=center,text={Text goes here}}}] (3,0) arc[radius=3cm, start angle=0, end angle=180];`, then this will look bad, and you're better off `\draw`'ing the arc without the decoration, and then putting the text along another arc that's `\path`'ed rather than `\draw`'n and which has its radius (and starting coordinate) adjusted by 0.35cm.

Answer (score 25):

The tikz library `decorations.text` allows you to place text along a path. The default placement of the text is not very nice if you are trying to have the text on a line (this seems to be because the default assumption is that the text *is* the line). You can use the `\pgftransform...` commands to shift the text around. These are described in Section 79 of the `pgf` manual. It's a bit cumbersome, since you can't use the node labels any more (they retain their coordinates).  Here's your example with the text shifted as I suggested in my comment to Martin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\draw [->, thick] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\pgftransformyshift{-.65cm}
\draw [decoration={text along path,
       text={Some more bent text},text align={center}},decorate]  (-3,0) to [bend right=45]  (3,0);
\draw [->, thick] (One) to  [bend left=45] (Two);
\pgftransformreset
\pgftransformyshift{.5cm}
\draw[decoration={text along path,
      text={Some bent text},text align={center}},decorate] (-3,0) to [bend left=45]  (3,0);
\node (mental) at (0,1.75) {};
\node (non-mental) at (0,-1.75) {};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]