# How to create roller coaster text?

Tags: positioning

I want to specify a curved base line (rising and falling like a roller coaster), then to have the text positioned such that it flows along that line. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're willing to use TikZ, have a look at [TikZ: Bend text so that it follows a line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/tikz-bend-text-so-that-it-follows-a-line)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Example 1: Text along a graph plot

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-text,pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-3,-5)(3,2)
\pstextpath[c](0,-0.5)
    {\psplot[linecolor=red,algebraic]{-2.75}{2.75}{x^2-4}}
    {\color{blue}\bf The graph of $y=f(x)=x^2-4$}
\psaxes[mathLabel=false,labelFontSize=\tiny]{->}(0,0)(-2.75,-4.75)(2.75,1.75)[$x$,-90][$y$,225]
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example 2: Text along an arc

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-text}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(7,3.5)
\pstextpath[c](0,0.25)
    {\psarcn[linecolor=red](3.5,0){3}{180}{0}}
    {\color{blue}\bf Merry Christmas and Happy New Year 2012}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Example 3: Text along an arbitrary curve

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-text}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(7,3.5)
\pstextpath[c](0,0.15)
    {\pscurve[linecolor=red](0,0)(1.5,2.5)(3.5,2)(5.5,2.5)(7,0)}
    {\color{blue}\bf Merry Christmas and Happy New Year 2012}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Note:

Compile each of them with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` sequence. Warning: `xelatex` cannot compile them correctly.

Comment: No, the pst-text package is incompitable with xelatex until now.

Comment: @gerry: Thanks for confirming such a incompatibility.