# How to bend a curve above text with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to connect two "positions" of text with an upwards curved arrow.
So far I have done this (trivially following the TikZ manual):

[image: current state]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n1) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If by any chance you know how to add text above it, it would be nice.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n1) to [out=45,in=135] (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And maybe a little bit like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n1) to [out=45,in=135] node[above] {some text here} (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And even fancier like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here\tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
\draw[->,very thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|some bent text here}}}]  (n1) to [out=45,in=135] (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Last approach taken from [this question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/tikz-bend-text-so-that-it-follows-a-line).

Answer (score 15):

Another idea:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here \tikz[remember picture] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n1)  .. controls +(1,1) and +(-1,1) .. node[above] {text above}(n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use `.. controls +(1,.5) and +(-1,.5) ..` if you want it even flatter.

Answer (score 14):

No bending but...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
How can I have from here \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \node[circle,fill=red!50] (n1) {}; a curved upwards arrow till here \tikz[remember picture,baseline=-0.5ex] \node[fill=blue!50] (n2) {};?
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n1) -- ++(0,2ex)coordinate (a) -- node[above]{some text here} ($(a-|n2)$) -- (n2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Add `\footnotesize` (or similar) to

```
node[above,font=\footnotesize]{some text here}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: I don't know... I spot two 90 degree bends.