# can I draw an arrow between 2 matrices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

```
\begin{bmatrix}
{2 \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol{A} ^{*}} & {\boldsymbol{O}} \\ 
{\boldsymbol{O}} & {3 \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol B^{*}}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
{4 \boldsymbol{E}} & {} \\
{} & {9 \boldsymbol{E}}
\end{bmatrix}
```

I want to draw a curve,from `2 \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol{A} ^{*}` to `4 \boldsymbol{E}`, it could be better if the curve can addon text/formula.how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Look at [**this answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210593/1424). It's for text, not math, but it should work the same in math mode. There will be many more examples. You can find them by searching, for example [**like this**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=[tikz-pgf]+remember+curved+arrows).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `nicematrix` which will create Tikz nodes for you and then, draw the arrow with a Tikz instruction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\NiceMatrixOptions{transparent}
\begin{document}
$\begin{bmatrix}[name=A]
{2 \boldsymbol A \boldsymbol{A} ^{*}} & {\boldsymbol{O}} \\ 
{\boldsymbol{O}} & {3 \boldsymbol B \boldsymbol B^{*}}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}[name=B]
{4 \boldsymbol{E}} & {} \\
{} & {9 \boldsymbol{E}}
\end{bmatrix}$
\tikz [remember picture, overlay] \draw [red,->] (A-1-1) to [bend left=45] (B-1-1) ; 
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]