# How place sloped text along a bended arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, text

In the following plot

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw,ultra thick,above right,] (USR) at (1,7) {User};
    \node[draw,ultra thick,below] (MNT) at (-1,-2) {Management};
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (MNT.north) to[ out=120, in=210,] (USR.west);
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (USR.east) to[ out=-30, in=50,] (MNT.east);
    %---
    \node[] (get) at (-1,4) {\large{GET}};
    % \node[below,yshift=-2mm] at (get) {\large{SET}};
    \node[] at (2,4) {\large{RESPONSE}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I cannot make the text `GET`, and `RESPONSE` be placed along the line (sloped).
I have tested options `pos=0.7`, `near end`, or `near start` do not work. Finally, the words appear at coordinates to show this example.

Comment: please look up sloped text on this website

Comment: @jsbibra yes, with `\path` does work as I was looking. I did not see the `\path` way of doing it :).

Comment: you could also go with this -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210593/197451

Comment: @jsbibra `\path[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (MNT.north) [out=120, in=210,sloped] edge node [below] {GET}  (USR.west);`

Comment: please see the edit also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw,ultra thick,above right,] (USR) at (1,7) {User};
    \node[draw,ultra thick,below] (MNT) at (-1,-2) {Management};
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (MNT.north) to[ out=120, in=210,]node[above,sloped] (get)  {\large{GET}} (USR.west) ;
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (USR.east) to[ out=-30, in=50,] (MNT.east);
    %---
    % \node[above,sloped] (get) at (-1,4) {\large{GET}};
    % \node[below,yshift=-2mm] at (get) {\large{SET}};
    % \node[] at (2,4) {\large{RESPONSE}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**OR**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows,shapes,decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    \node[draw,ultra thick,above right,] (USR) at (1,7) {User};
    \node[draw,ultra thick,below] (MNT) at (-1,-2) {Management};
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal] (MNT.north) to[ out=120, in=210,]node[above,sloped] (get)  {\large{GET}} (USR.west) ;

    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1ex}}
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal, postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={
    |\myshift|some bent text here}}}] (USR.east) to[ out=-30, in=50,] (MNT.east);
    %---
    % \node[above,sloped] (get) at (-1,4) {\large{GET}};
    % \node[below,yshift=-2mm] at (get) {\large{SET}};
    % \node[] at (2,4) {\large{RESPONSE}};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I control the position, the distance between the two nodes? in the two types. I would like to place the text closer to User node

Comment: page 646 of the pgf manual here -- https://ctan.asis.ai/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to follow the curve, you have to use the `decorations.text` library and some tricks, like in the following:

[image: text along curve]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node[draw,ultra thick,above right,] (USR) at (1,7) {User};
    \node[draw,ultra thick,below] (MNT) at (-1,-2) {Management};
    
    \def\shft#1{\raisebox{1ex}} % Vertical shift to be used as an argument in the path decoration
    
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\large\shft|GET SET}}}] (MNT.north) to[ out=120, in=210,] (USR.west);
    
    \draw[-latex,line width=1.mm,teal,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\large\shft|RESPONSE}}}] (USR.east) to[ out=-30, in=50,] (MNT.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like we wrote the same solution but js bibra beat me to it ;)

Comment: @SebGlab yes, it is a similar solution :-)