# How to duplicate a bent line and change its position keeping its arrow using tikzpicture environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using the following answer to illustrate what I want: [TikZ: Bend text so that it follows a line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550).

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}

% Bend curves from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\myshift#1{\scriptsize\raisebox{1ex}}
    \node (Start) at (0,0) {Output};
    \node (End) at (-5,2) {Arrival};
    \draw [-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|this is an example}}}] (End) to [bend left=-5] (Start);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

I would like to add one more line without text below it. This pair must have its arrow, possibly bigger (`-latex`):

[image: What I want]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add as many `postaction` and `preaction` as you wish. Just add one more!

### Update based on manooooh's comment:

> But there are two differents arrows. If possible, I want the lines to
>   be one (and a little more stuck): so one "big" arrow.

Then there is no need to use multiple `postaction`, it's enough to use the `double` key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

% Bend curves from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\myshift#1{\scriptsize\raisebox{2ex}}
    \node (Start) at (0,0) {Output};
    \node (End) at (-5,2) {Arrival};
    \draw [arrows = {-Latex[length=0pt 3 0]},double distance=5pt,double,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|this is an example}}}] 

    (End) to [bend left=-5] (Start);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: double-key]

### Old answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

% Bend curves from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22316/152550
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\myshift#1{\scriptsize\raisebox{1ex}}
    \node (Start) at (0,0) {Output};
    \node (End) at (-5,2) {Arrival};
    \draw [-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\myshift|this is an example}}}] 
    [postaction={draw,black,thick,arrows = {-Latex[width'=0pt .5,length=15pt]}
,transform canvas={yshift=-5mm}}]
    (End) to [bend left=-5] (Start);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: postaction]

Comment: Thanks!! But there are two differents arrows. If possible, I want the lines to be one (and a little more stuck): so one "big" arrow.

Comment: then no need to add one more `postaction`, just use the `double` key

Comment: i just updated my answer

Comment: You've taken "big" seriously... `:D`

Comment: Is it too big? You can refine this by reading pages 185; 186 and 187 of manual `3.0.1a`.