# TikZ: Bend text that has macros e.g., superscripts

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a new TikZ user and I started using the package to create FSMs. It all worked fine until I came across the issue of naming edges that are bent.

There is a relevant question for text on edges [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22314/tikz-bend-text-so-that-it-follows-a-line). But when I try to adapt it to my problem, namely to use it as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$};  
    \node (Two) at ( 3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};

    \def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
    \draw [->,
           thick,
           postaction={decorate,
                       decoration={text along path,
                                   text align=center,
                                   text={|\sffamily\myshift|SUPERSCRIPT^{TEST}}
                                   }
                      }
          ] (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It will not work. The `SUPERSCRIPT^{TEST}` causes an error. And I have not found a way to use text that has no superscripts in that way. Is there a work-around for this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're trying to use `^` which is a math mode command in text mode which is why you get the error. If you want to superscript regular text, you should use `\textsuperscript` instead of `^`. Inside the `text` argument of the `decoration`, however, the macro needs to be protected with `{...}`. You are also missing the `\end{tikzpicture}` line. So the following works.

Also, the `\myshift` macro from the original answer isn't needed; instead you can use the `raise` key inside the decoration.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
       text align=center,raise=-2.5ex,
       text={|\sffamily|SUPERSCRIPT{\textsuperscript{TEST}}}}}] 
  (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

This is not a perfect solution, since the material you put in the `{...}` will be treated as a single unit with respect to the path, and if it is long, you will get very unwelcome results:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$}; 
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
       text align=center,raise=-2.5ex,
       text={|\sffamily|SUPERSCRIPT{\textsuperscript{REALLY LONG TEST}}}}}] 
   (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of second code]

Answer (score 2):

The defined but not used macro `\myshift` gave me an idea to come away from `\textsuperscript` und change the font size and amount of "raise" in the middle of the given text. I must admit that I guessed the difference, so it is probably not the best possible answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$};
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{-2.5ex}}
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
       text align=center,raise=-2.5ex,
       text={|\sffamily|SUPERSCRIPT{\textsuperscript{REALLY LONG TEST}}}}}]
   (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}

Alternative:
\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (One) at (-3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$One$};
\node (Two) at (3,0) [shape=circle,draw] {$Two$};
\def\myshift#1{\raisebox{1.5ex}}
\draw [->,thick,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,
       text align=center,raise=-2.5ex,
       text={|\sffamily|SUPERSCRIPT\ |\sffamily\tiny\myshift|REALLY LONG TEST}}}]
   (One) to [bend right=45]  (Two);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]